# How can I find out the affixes and roots of a Greek word?

Tags: ancient-greek, suffixes, dictionary

I suspect that hosos is derived from hos and os. Which dictionaries will help me find that out?

Comment: Side comment, given that you are asking a lot of questions about ancient Greek: I would recommend putting transliterations in parentheses and using the actual Greek letters.

Comment: Most dictionaries will point out compound words. And since [LSJ](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=osos&la=greek#lexicon) is easily accessible, you can just use that.